# How to push a docker image to azure app service using terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-appservice, azure-rm

I'm creating an azure web app for containers with terraform but keep receiving this error

here's my code:

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "myApp-plan" {
  name                = "myApp-plan"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.myResourceGroup.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myResourceGroup.name}"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "S2"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "myApp" {
  name                = "myApp"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myResourceGroup.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.myResourceGroup.location}"
  service_plan_id     = "${azurerm_service_plan.myApp-plan.id}"

  https_only            = true

  app_settings = {} #some env variables
    
  site_config { 
    minimum_tls_version  = "1.2"
    linux_fx_version     = "DOCKER|jboss/keycloak:11.0.0"
  }

}
```

when I run `terraform apply` I receive this:

```
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with azurerm_linux_web_app.keycloak_app,
│   on main.tf line 98, in resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "myApp":
│   98:     linux_fx_version     = "DOCKER|jboss/keycloak:11.0.0"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "site_config.0.linux_fx_version": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.
```

Any advice pls?

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: version = "~>2.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're pinned to version 2.0 I cannot see any documentation for the resource named `azurerm_linux_web_app`. I do see `azurerm_app_service` though.

It looks like the argument you're trying to set is [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.0.0/docs/resources/app_service#linux_fx_version)

Based on the documentation, you will need to call your resource `azurerm_app_service` and use the version `2.0` of the provider. There may be other attributes you need to adjust so please check the correct documentation version.

You may have been referring to the latest version documentation which has a resource named `azurerm_linux_web_app` and a [site_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#always_on) block that **doesn't** support a user specified `linux_fx_version` argument.